# Facepile callbacks

Tags: jquery, facebook

I wanna set my html div height dynamically. I have added Facepile widget. I cannot use jquery ready function as FB facepile loading time is not gauranteed.

so , if FB provides the callback to facebook facepile load event, then i can set the height.
any other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it took me a while to find a solution, but I finally did. There's an event that is fired when the facepile is finished rendering. So you run your code when that event is triggered like so:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function(response) {
    //then put whatever code you want to run here
    var fbHeight = jQuery('div.fb-facepile').outerHeight();
}
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/